# Power Automate Workflow

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I'm trying to figure out how to send a reccuring message to an individual person through Teams(work). I figured out how to send a message to one person using the flowbot but i'm having difficulity figuring out how to schedule the flow to run every 3rd wedneday of the month.

[image]

Comment: This is not power-automate-desktop. What are you struggling with? You set the settings in the recurrence action.

Comment: @CobyC thanks for answering! I can't access power-automate deskop. My work license only allows us to use the web version. I set the setting in the recurrence action, but it's not sending the message to the user when I want. It keeps sending it daily despite setting it to send a message the 3rd of every month.

Comment: Please share a snip of your Recurrence action fully expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the schedule every day and use a condition to check the day of the week and the week of the month.

Use 2 *Initialize variables* actions, one for the day of the week and one for the week of the month.

`WeekInMonth` formula: `add(div(dayOfMonth(utcNow()),7),1)`

`DayOfWeekNow` formula: `dayOfWeek(utcNow())`

Mon = 1, Tue = 2, Wed = 3 ..etc..

so for your condition you want the check to be day 3 (Wednesday) and week 3, that will give you every 3rd Wednesday of the month.

[image: schedulewithvariables]
[image: conditionalcheck]